# “Unresolved reference” in MainActivity.kt calling a TextView?

Tags: android-studio, kotlin

when I try to use a TextView in my activity_main.xml, I get a “Unresolved reference” in my MainActivity.kt (even before try building)? I just can’t see what I’m doing wrong!

I've highlighted the error at the end of the MainActivity.

Any help appreciated.

**MainActivity.kt**

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    val carouselRecyclerview = findViewById<CarouselRecyclerview>(R.id.recycler)
    val list = ArrayList<DataModel>()
    list.add(DataModel(R.drawable.ad_astra, "Adastra"))
    list.add(DataModel(R.drawable.beach_bum, "Beach Bum"))
    list.add(DataModel(R.drawable.dark_phoenix, "Dark Phoenix"))
    list.add(DataModel(R.drawable.glass, "Glass"))
    val adapter = DataAdapter(list)
    carouselRecyclerview.adapter = adapter
    carouselRecyclerview.set3DItem(true)
    carouselRecyclerview.setAlpha(true)
    val carouselLayoutManager = carouselRecyclerview.getCarouselLayoutManager()
    val currentlyCenterPosition = carouselRecyclerview.getSelectedPosition()
    carouselRecyclerview.setItemSelectListener(object : CarouselLayoutManager.OnSelected {
        override fun onItemSelected(position: Int) {
            //Cente item
            Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity, list[position].text, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            ShowMeIt.text = "Why does cause a Unresolved reference?"
            ShowMeIt.text = list[position].text
        }})
}
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">
<com.jackandphantom.carouselrecyclerview.CarouselRecyclerview
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/recycler"/>
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/ShowMeIt"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_marginEnd="186dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="186dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="106dp"
    android:text="Hello" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to define on MainActivity.kt like this

`val ShowMeIt= findViewById<TextView>(R.id.ShowMeIt)`